# How to add blinking circle inside draw:inRect: method of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Inside my custom UIView and `draw:inRect` initializer I have following code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    //...

    let axisPath = UIBezierPath()

    axisPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: paddingHorizontal + 20, y: paddingVertical))
    axisPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: leftOffset, y: bottomOffset))
    axisPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - paddingHorizontal, y: bottomOffset))
    axisPath.lineWidth = 1

    UIColor.black.set()
    axisPath.stroke()

    var currentIndex = 0

    for yearData in data {

      //...

        let circle = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: x - 4, y: y - 4, width: 8, height: 8), cornerRadius: 4)
        circle.fill()
        circle.stroke() //red circle, I need to make it blinking somehow
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

The result is following:

[image]

Now I need to make red circle blinking:) How can I do that?

Comment: I would recommend a separate `CAShapeLayer` to draw the circle and animate with Core Animation

Comment: I did like you said, and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach. Use `draw(_:)` only for the static part of the graph.

The blinking red circle should be a simple little subview added over the graph view. Use a repeating `UIView` animation to fade the little circle view in and out using its `alpha` property.

See [How do I get this fade animation to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841798/how-do-i-get-this-fade-animation-to-work) for an example of performing the blinking animation.

Answer (score -1):

Setup a NSTimer and draw and undraw your red circle based on that.  You have at least two choices:  Create the red circle as an UIView and just set Hidden flag appropriately, or toggle a flag on your timer and invalidate the area encompassed by the red circle.